# How to understand this Arrays and loops in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, syntax, nokogiri

Regarding the following code:

### update:

(thank you DGM and The Tin Man for recomendation on code and apneadiving for explanation.)

```
#################
# get main page
#################
  rows = doc.xpath('//table[@class="articulos"]/tr[td[5]/p/b]')
  i = 0
  details = rows.each do |row|
    detail = {}  
    [
      [:sku, 'td[3]/text()'],
      [:desc, 'td[4]/text()'],
      [:stock, "td[5]/p[@title]"],
      [:price, 'td[6]/text()']
    ].each do |name, xpath|
        detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip

      end
    i = i + 1
    if detail[:sku] != ""
          price = detail[:price].split

          if price[1] == "D"
              currency = 144
          else
              currency = 168
          end
          stock = detail[:stock].gsub(/[^\d]/, '')
          cost = price[0].gsub(",", "").to_f
  end
```

- Is the first `i = 0`, `i = i + 1` neccesary?
- What syntax is this using? `details = rows.each do |row|`
- Why would you want to use `detail = {}`? What is this doing?
- I do understand `.each do |name,xpath|` because it is in the order: `name`, `xpath`.
- I guess `detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip` is saying that, if I call `detail[:sku]`, it will make that row at that `xpath` to a string strip.

for what I understand after reading [Ruby Poignant Book](http://mislav.uniqpath.com/poignant-guide/book) reading the code I wrote above I can maybe translate to Ruby logic words?. If that is not to insulting for Ruby Experts,haha.

First we have a loop of one method, with an array of arrays, inside another one.

```
variable = variable.method block |block argument|
  variable = {block}
  [ array of arrays
    [ symbol_1, 'string'],
    [ symbol_2, 'string'],
    [ symbol_3, 'string'],
    [ symbol_4, 'string'],
    [ symbol_5, 'string'],
    [ symbol_6, 'string']
  ].method block |symbol, string|
    variable[symbol] = variable.method(method argument).method.kernel_method
  end block
end block
```

??? is this correct? now I need to explain that using the method , variable, and arguments actual names in the code, lets see:

The rows variable gets a collect message to collect a row of an array of arrays containing the symbol and xpath and for each block of arrays the row and xpath wil be applied a kernel method strip?

Comment: You need to learn ruby my dear friend.
I'd recommend that you read Why's Poignant Guide.

This is just ruby syntax, you need to learn about it to understand.

Comment: Yes, everything here is just standard Ruby language and Nokogiri library usage; quite basic really.  Unfortunately there is no shortcut here but to learn that language and library.

Comment: The code works but that needs a refactor, it has code duplication and unnecesary variables.

Comment: "detail << detail I know this is called a push? so why do anyone want to push some same name haha..." Take the time to read your code more carefully: It isn't doing what you think. `details << detail` Notice that it is "detailS", not "detail".

Comment: @JCorcuera what is your recomendation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The first i = 0, i = i + 1 (why is
>   that neccesary here?)

it's useless, you're right

> details = rows.collect do |row| what
>   syntax is this for? a array? or what
>   class is using from nokogiri? does
>   nokogiri has anything to do with this
>   or is it only RUBY handling an object.

it's sheer ruby style, it loops the elements of what should be an Array.

It also recreates an Array stored in `details` containing every element declared at the end of the loop. Here it's `detail`

> detail = {} you see this. why would
>   you want to use this? is this doing
>   something I am not seing?

It initializes `detail` to an empty Hash which is then filled in the `collect` loop.

> I do understand .collect do
>   |name,xpath| because of the top is in
>   order in name , xpath detail[name] =
>   row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip I guess
>   this is saying that if I call
>   detail[:sku] it will make that row at
>   that xpath to a string strip?

Correct.

> what does .map do? is there a syntax
>   tutorial in nokogiri page for this?

`map` loops all the elements of what should be a Hash. It creates an Array containing links. Duplicates of links are removed from this Array thanks to `uniq!`

Notice the bang at then end of this function, it means it changes the object.

> and why did he had to repeat all data
>   in the #walk trough paginator instead
>   of just using idk some variable?

Don't understand this question.

> detail << detail I know this is called
>   a push? so why do anyone want to push
>   some same name haha...

It's a push but it's `details << detail` so logic is safe.

To conclude, it's not beautiful code but it seems functional :)

Comment: The rows variable gets a collect message to collect a row of an array of arrays containing the symbol and xpath and for each block of arrays the row and xpath wil be applied a kernel method strip?

Answer (score 2):

One thing to note, I did this in my own code recently:

```
      detail = {}
      [
              [:sku, 'td[3]/text()'],
              [:desc, 'td[4]/text()'],
              [:qty, 'td[5]/text()'],
              [:qty2, 'td[5]/p/b/text()'],
              [:title, 'td[5]/p/@title'],
              [:price, 'td[6]/text()']
      ].collect do |name, xpath|
              detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
      end
```

The result of the collect statement is thrown way, and the side effect of stuffing things into `detail` is the main concern.  The collect could be changed to an each, in this case.

```
      detail = {}
      [
              [:sku, 'td[3]/text()'],
              [:desc, 'td[4]/text()'],
              [:qty, 'td[5]/text()'],
              [:qty2, 'td[5]/p/b/text()'],
              [:title, 'td[5]/p/@title'],
              [:price, 'td[6]/text()']
      ].each do |name, xpath|
              detail[name] = row.at_xpath(xpath).to_s.strip
      end
```

Comment: "The collect could be changed to an each, in this case." In my opinion, "could" should be "should". Using a `map` or a `collect` as an `each` is not good programming that could have unintended side-effects depending on how it's used.

Comment: Tin Man so your opinion is to change .map and .collect to .each ?

Comment: Only in that spot...   collect and map (same function, different name) return a value, which in this location is not used.  `foo = bar.collect {}` vs `bar.each{}`  If you don't collect the return value, don't use collect. :)