# Need clarification with 'each-do' block in my ruby code

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Given an html file:

```
<div>
    <div class="NormalMid">
        <span class="style-span">
            "Data 1:"
            <a href="http://site.com/data/1">1</a>
            <a href="http://site.com/data/2">2</a>
        </span>
    </div>
   ...more divs
    <div class="NormalMid">
        <span class="style-span">
            "Data 20:"  
            <a href="http://site.com/data/20">20</a>
            <a href="http://site.com/data/21">21</a>
            <a href="http://site.com/data/22">22</a>
            <a href="http://site.com/data/23">23</a>
        </span>
    </div>
    ...more divs
</div
```

Using these SO posts as reference:
[How do I integrate these two conditions block codes to mine in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462081/how-do-i-integrate-these-two-conditions-block-codes-to-mine-in-ruby)
and
[How to understand this Arrays and loops in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458255/how-to-understand-this-arrays-and-loops-in-ruby)

My code:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'pp'
require 'open-uri'

data_file = 'site.htm'
file = File.open(data_file, 'r')
html = open(file)
page = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
page.encoding = 'utf-8'

rows = page.xpath('//div[@class="NormalMid"]')
details = rows.collect do |row|
    detail = {}
    [
        [row.children.first.element_children,row.children.first.element_children],
    ].each do |part, link|
        data = row.children[0].children[0].to_s.strip
        links = link.collect {|item| item.at_xpath('@href').to_s.strip}
        detail[data.to_sym] = links
    end
    detail
end
details.reject! {|d| d.empty?}
pp details
```

The output:

```
[{:"Data 1:"=>
   ["http://www.site.com/data/1",
    "http://www.site.com/data/2"]},
 ...
 {:"Data 20 :"=>
   ["http://www.site.com/data/20",
    "http://www.site.com/data/21",
    "http://www.site.com/data/22",
    "http://www.site.com/data/20",]},
 ... 
}]
```

Everything is going good, exactly what I wanted.

**BUT** if you change these lines of code:

```
 detail = {}
    [
       [row.children.first.element_children,row.children.first.element_children],
    ].each do |part, link|
```

to:

```
 detail = {}
    [
       [row.children.first.element_children],
    ].each do |link|
```

I get the output of

```
[{:"Data 1:"=>
   ["http://www.site.com/data/1"]},
 ...
 {:"Data 20 :"=>
   ["http://www.site.com/data/20"]},
 ... 
}]
```

Only the first anchor href is stored in the array.

I just need some clarification on why its behaving that way because the argument `part` in the argument list is not being used, I figure I didn't need it there. But my program doesn't work correctly if I delete the corresponding `row.children.first.element_children` as well.

What is going on in the `[[obj,obj],].each do` block? I just started ruby a week ago, and I'm still getting used to the syntax, any help will be appreciated. Thank You :D

**EDIT** 
`rows[0].children.first.element_children[0]` will have the output

```
Nokogiri::XML::Element:0xcea69c name="a" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0xcea648
name="href" value="http://www.site.com/data/1">] children[<Nokogiri::XML::Text:0xcea1a4
"1">]>
```

`puts rows[0].children.first.element_children[0]`

```
 <a href="http://www.site.com/data/1">1</a>
```

Comment: could you provide the contents (either actual or made up) of `row.children.first.element_children`

Comment: You wrote a simple code,in a more complex way.

Comment: Oh no too much clutter on my response :S
@Bala - I have edited my post to show you the outputs
ArupRakshit - Yah I think I over complicated the way I did things. Since I'm new to Ruby I dont know that many idioms, and when I saw that construct I thought it was the 'Ruby' way of doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made your code overly complicated. Looking at your code,it seems you are trying to get something like below:

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML::Document.parse <<-eotl
<div>
    <div class="NormalMid">
        <span class="style-span">
            "Data 1:"
            <a href="http://site.com/data/1">1</a>
            <a href="http://site.com/data/2">2</a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="NormalMid">
        <span class="style-span">
            "Data 20:"  
            <a href="http://site.com/data/20">20</a>
            <a href="http://site.com/data/21">21</a>
            <a href="http://site.com/data/22">22</a>
            <a href="http://site.com/data/23">23</a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div
eotl

rows = doc.xpath("//div[@class='NormalMid']/span[@class='style-span']")
val = rows.map do |row|
    [row.at_xpath("./text()").to_s.tr('"','').strip,row.xpath(".//@href").map(&:to_s)]
end

Hash[val]
# => {"Data 1:"=>["http://site.com/data/1", "http://site.com/data/2"],
#     "Data 20:"=>
#      ["http://site.com/data/20",
#       "http://site.com/data/21",
#       "http://site.com/data/22",
#       "http://site.com/data/23"]}
```

> What is going on in the [[obj,obj],].each do block?

Look the below 2 parts:

```
[[1],[4,5]].each do |a|
  p a
end
# >> [1]
# >> [4, 5]

[[1,2],[4,5]].each do |a,b|
    p a, b
end
# >> 1
# >> 2
# >> 4
# >> 5
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I found out about irb and now i can just test things I don't understand, I think your explanation on the bottom of your post helped me understand what was going on :D